# How can I apply for an Evernote developer token?

Tags: evernote

I am trying to apply for an Evernote developer token, but it seems like I must create a developer account in order to do this (https://dev.evernote.com/doc/). When I go to request the token, they are asking for my developer username. The this is: I don't have a developer username. Is there someone from the Evernote developer team that can provide guidance on this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a dev account here:
https://sandbox.evernote.com/

The Create Account link is at bottom.

Get a developer token here:
https://sandbox.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action

I just submitted my request for API Key Activation and had to follow the steps above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was really helpful.